# Modifying integer with buffer-overflow

Tags: integer, buffer-overflow

I am trying to modify an integer in a struct using buffer-overflow but I cant figure out in what format the integer is stored.

I did some test code:

```
    struct {
    char beginningWord[3];
    int32_t middleInt;
    char endingWord[3];
} testStruct;

testStruct.middleInt = 5;
strcpy(testStruct.endingWord, "123");
strcpy(testStruct.beginningWord, "AAAA0000FFF");
```

This changes the endingWord from "123" to "FFF" and the integer from 5 to 808464432. What should I overwrite to integers memory slots with to change it to 9 for example?

Comment: 808464432 = 0x30303030 = "0000" but this fact is not obvious since you are apparently printing the results in decimal, which just totally hides what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

9 of the right width (32 bits) cannot reliably be copied by `strcpy`. It would look like this in hexadecimal:

```
00000009
```

Commonly it would be stored in memory this way (called Little Endian)

```
09 00 00 00
```

This is not a string consisting of the characters '0' and '9', it's four bytes with values 9 and 0.

The `09` and the first `00` can be copied by `strcpy`, but then `strcpy` stops since `00` signals the end of the string. So two bytes of the integer (and `endingWord`) are not written to and retain their previous value. The resulting value would not be 9 if the high bytes are non-zero to start. `memcpy` can copy data like this reliably, including the "non-final" zeroes.

As a character, the `09` would be interpreted as (or written as) `\t` (tab character) in the ASCII encoding.